# Laravel 8: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-8

It always show this error- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .I searched online,they say this error is because what in the foreach() is not array but I checked already,it is a array, I don't know what is the problem and how to solve the problem...

Blade

```
@foreach ($employee->model_has_permissions as $model_has_permission)                                                             
   @if (in_array('21', $model_has_permission->permission_id))checked="checked" @endif
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
$model_has_permissions = model_has_permissions::where('model_id','LIKE',$search_text)->get()->toArray();
      
return view('search_result',compact('employees','families','educations','experiences','model_has_permissions'));
```

Comment: Have you tried `dump()`-ing `$employee->model_has_permissions` and `$model_has_permissions`? It seems like you're trying to access `$employee->model_has_permissions` instead of `$model_has_permissions`

Comment: @ felixbmmm if I user $model_has_permissions,it will show this error- Trying to get property 'permission_id' of non-object

Comment: which variable are you trying to loop over exactly?? what are you trying to do??

Comment: @zahid hasan emon I would like to let the checkbox checked based on the permission which the user have in the database.

Comment: I noticed on your `compact()` method, you put `employees` and when you tried to loop the model_has_permissions, it is `employee`. Plus, can you make sure on the view side, this `$employee->model_has_permission` exists?

Comment: @felixbmmm ya,it should be employee, when I put employee->model_has_permission, it shows this error- Property [model_has_permissions] does not exist on this collection instance. How can I check is it exist? because the education,experience and the other ,I use this way and it works

Comment: You need to include this `model_has_permissions` relationship on your employee model, then call it on your controller for the view to be able to use

Answer (score 0):

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() it is because
$employee->model_has_permissions variable pass a empty value . so before starting, the loop you have to check is the loop variable comes with a value

```
@if($employee->model_has_permissions->count()>0)
@foreach ($employee->model_has_permissions as $model_has_permission)                                                             
   @if (in_array('21', $model_has_permission->permission_id))checked="checked" @endif
@endforeach
@else
<h6> No data found</h6>
@endif
```